# DataTable events and row state

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am allowing my users to add / edit / delete data in a DataGridView that is bound to a DataTable. That all works fine. The data gets updated back to the database fine. However, I have some fields in the DataTable that I do not want to be visible in the DataGridView, such as CreatedOn and CreatedBy. I need to write values to these columns based on the state of the row before they get updated to the data adapter. 
In this case, should I wire up some event handlers for TableNewRow and RowChanged in the datatable and manipulate the row columns that way before the data adapter is updated and AcceptChanges has occured?

Thanks for any thoughts.

Ryan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I figured out and it works great. After I pass the data table back to my data access class, I loop the rows in the table and check the DataRowState. I set the column values based on the DataRowState.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
            if (row.RowState == DataRowState.Added)
                {
                row["CreatedOn"] = DateTime.Now;
                row["CreatedBy"] = GlobalProp.UserName;
                row["ModifiedOn"] = DateTime.Now;
                row["ModifiedBy"] = GlobalProp.UserName;
                }
            else if (row.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)
                {
                row["ModifiedOn"] = DateTime.Now;
                row["ModifiedBy"] = GlobalProp.UserName;
                }
            }
```

Hope that helps someone else!

R